# jdbc sqlserver Exception: The query has timed out

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that it was running very well until today. There was no change in the code.

I have a connection with my SQL Server, and when query run (if it takes more than 1 second)  I have this error:

"Exception: The query has timed out"

Code:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection   ("jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=xx;user=xx;password=yyyy");
var stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.setQueryTimeout(5);
stmt.executeQuery("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15.00'")
var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

---

I set timeout query in 5 seconds but I didn't work.

This project is running on our new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8